# update with joining three tables

Tags: oracle

I need help in the below query :

Req:  I HAVE THREE COLUMNS FROM THREE TABLES

```
TABLE3.FIRSTNAME  TABLE3.LASTNAME TABLE1.ACCNAME
HAR               WAL             HAR WAL
ATT               SSS             ATT SSS
```

I CREATED BELOW UPDATE QUERY TO UPDATE TABLE AND I NEED TO UPDATE TABLE 1ACCNAME WITH FISRTNAME LASTNAME BUT BELOW QUERY THROWING ERROR :"Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row"

IM USING oRACLE SQL DEV

```
UPDATE BPD.TABLE1  
  SET BPD.TABLE1.ACCNAME  = 
     ( select BPD.TABLE3.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || BPD.TABLE3.LASTNAME 
       from   ((           BPD.TABLE1 
                INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE2 ON BPD.TABLE2.ACCID = BCPD.TABLE1.ID)
               INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE3 ON BCPD.TABLE2.CONTACTID =BPD.TABLE.ID  ) 
       WHERE  BPD.TABLE1.ID IN 
          ( select BCPD.TABLE1.ID from BCPD.TABLE1 where rownum >=1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO BPD.TABLE1 t1
  USING (select t11.ID,
                BPD.TABLE3.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || BPD.TABLE3.LASTNAME AS ACCNAME
           from BPD.TABLE1 t11
           INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE2
             ON BPD.TABLE2.ACCID = BPD.TABLE1.ID
           INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE3
             ON BPD.TABLE2.CONTACTID = BPD.TABLE.ID) d
    ON (t1.ID = d.ID)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET t1.ACCNAME = d.ACCNAME;
```

Comment: thanks for your help however when i was running this I got error saying Missing keyword .ORA-00905

Comment: one more que on second join in your query "INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE3 (are we missing anything here)
             BCPD.TABLE2.CONTACTID = BPD.TABLE.ID) d"?

Comment: The keyword `ON` was missing in the eighth line.

Comment: appreciate your support and quick reply .now I'm getting error ORA-00969 Missing ON keyword .

Comment: The `ON` condition of the `USING` clause has to be put into parentheses.

Comment: it worked and im sorry but getting another error ORA-00904: Invalid identifier on line 6 on " = BCPD.TABLE1.ID" I don't know if this is because of alias name ,

Comment: It appears that the schema name for TABLE1 should be `BPD`, not `BCPD`. I've changed all the schema names to `BPD` - if any are wrong feel free to change them to whatever you'd like.

Comment: hi A very good morning , I tried one more option by adding MAX and Group by below :MERGE INTO BPD.TABLE1 T1
USING (
          SELECT T2.ACCID,
                 MAX(T3.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || T3.LASTNAME) AS ACCNAME
            FROM
            -- CREATED AND USED THE ALIASES
           BPD.TABLE2 T2
           INNER JOIN BPD.TABLE3 T3
          ON T2.CONTACTID = T3.ID 
          GROUP BY T2.ACCID
      ) D ON ( T1.ID = D.ACCID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
   SET T1.ACCNAME = D.ACCNAME;

but now getting error:
ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source